# How to filter equal strings and get just one of each

Tags: swift

I have a list of items that contains groups, when I print them, it shows all items.

```
MOVIE: Cartoon Multi Subtitles
MOVIE: Cartoon Multi Subtitles
MOVIE: Cartoon Multi Subtitles
MOVIE: Cartoon Multi Subtitles
MOVIE: Cartoon Multi Subtitles

MOVIE: English
MOVIE: English
MOVIE: English
MOVIE: English
MOVIE: English
```

I tried this way:

```
let item = playlist?.objects.map({ $0.group != group })
-> Unable to infer closure type in the current context
```

And this way:

```
    for group in item! {
        if group.self != group {
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(group), style: .default) {
                action in
            })
            print(group)
        }
    }

   @IBAction func button(_ sender: Any) {

        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let item = playlist?.objects.map({ $0.group != group })

        for group in item! {
            if group.self == group {
                alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: String(group), style: .default) {
                    action in
                })
                print(group)
            }
        }

        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel))

        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

What I want to archive is to remove duplicate groups.

Comment: Simply add those movies to a `Set`.

Comment: let item: Set = playlist?.objects.map({ $0.group }) -> Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to specified type 'Set'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After mapping the group names, put that array into a set to get the unique group names.

```
let uniqueGroups = Set(playlist?.objects.map({ $0.group != group }) ?? [])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I get similar error -> Cannot convert value of type 'Set<String>' to expected argument type 'String?'

Comment: Right. uniqueGroups is a Set of String. You need to iterate the set or convert it to an array or build a String from the elements of the Set.

Comment: Hi again, I just wonder what is the equivalent of .map on Core Data?

Comment: @twix That needs to be asked as its own question. I've never used Core Data.